# WordPress category gives 404 after moving to a different domain

Tags: categories, 404-error, htaccess

I just moved a site from one domain to another and now category links are all 404. I have flushed the rewrite rules, recreated the .htaccess file but still it throws up 404.

Weird thing is that if I delete `.htaccess` file, then the posts are still accessible by `domain.com/postname/` and when I save permalinks, then it is created there. So can it be the case it is using some other .htaccess file? Possibly some fallback that I am not aware of?

**Re-Edit:** ***Tag pages don't work fine***. Its all weird. Tags generally give 404, one of them opened a non 404 page but not what it should be (i.e. posts listing under that tag). And a category redirects itself to one of the posts. This all led me to conclude that tags were working but they are not. Also everything works, when I turn off the permalinks.

I am using a custom slug for category "cat" and not the default "category" but reverting to the default doesn't solve anything. Any clues?

**Edit:** I saw [Ipstenu's sticky on WP forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-31-master-list?replies=22) and found that Advanced Permalinks are known to have a problem with WP 3.1, so I disabled it and recreated by permalinks but still no joy. What did I miss?

So far, I have tried recreating permalinks, flushing rewrite rules by calling `global $wp_rewrite; $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();` in `functions.php`, deleting `rewrite_rules` in `options table` & even deleting `.htaccess` file. So I am clueless and would appreciate if someone can give me a clue how it can be fixed.

**Further Edit:** If I delete the .htaccess file, the site behaves if it was there and I can browse pretty permalinks without any issue (.htaccess file is not there in the WP root) but when I resave permalinks, it is created there. So can there be some kind of fallback for .htaccess because this shouldn't be possible without rules in .htaccess?

**EDIT:** I am still stuck at the issue. Can anyone please help me out?

**Final Edit:** Is there anything left in the wild that I can do to troubleshoot this issue? I have lost hope on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying everything out, nothing worked but then all of a sudden, deleting .htaccess file and re-saving permalinks did the job.

Comment: Just for the sake of mentioning it, this problem creep in again and I don't know how it was resolved if it even was.

Answer (score 0):

Setup [301: Moved Permanently](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2) redirects! [This post](http://yoast.com/move-wordpress-blog-domain-10-steps/) should be helpful

Comment: I have those already and I believe this is not affecting the new site in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that your .htaccess file is active - ie in your apache virtual host settings make sure you've got something like `AllowOverride All` in the  section